Odd-Even-town equivalent to K_n
An Odd-Even-town is a family of sets such that each set has an even size and intersections
of different sets are of odd size. In a mathematical way:
$ A = \{A_1, A_2, ...,A_k\}$
$\forall i,\,|A_i| \equiv 0 \pmod 2$
$\forall i\neq j,\,|A_i \cap A_j| \equiv 1 \pmod 2$
My question is to determine the maximum size of an Odd-Even-town with n citizens.
I assume it depends if n is odd or even. For odd $n$ then $k = n$ , otherwise $k = n-1$.
What I did was make incidence matrix of $A$ and then multiply it with its transpose from left $A^TA$ and what I got was a matrix where on the diagonal I got all zeroes, otherwise 1. Then I computed rank($A^TA$) and got rank $k$ or $k-1$ but realized that $A^TA$ is the same matrix as the adjacency matrix of $K_k$.
I would like to know if it is some known thing about Odd-Even-town is k = n iff $K_n$ has odd number of vertices?
I would like to know why $K_n$ is showing in this problem and prove this relation.

I am not precisely sure what the question is. If $n$ is odd, then $K_n$ has an odd number of vertices by definition of $K_n$. If you must relate the Odd-Even Town problem to the complete graph, then let each club be a vertex, and let two clubs be adjacent if their intersection is odd. This is a complete graph precisely when every club has odd intersection with every other club except itself.

So if I understand correctly we can say that a club is our vertex and an edge between 2 vertices is if a club shares a citizen and if n is odd then a maximum number of clubs can be n ? and if n is even then n-1? What I don't understand is how to prove this relation.

Okay, it looks like you are looking for an explanation of why the complete graph is showing up in this problem. I am happy to write an answer to this question, but I am busy now, and so I will return to this later. What I would say for now is that thinking of this in terms of the complete graph merely restates the Odd-Even town question in a different form. Actually answering the question requires linear algebra (at least for all the proofs I am aware of).
